# Using a structure defined in C header as a Python data type

Tags: python, python-c-api

How do I use a C struct foo, defined in a header file as a datatype in my Python code?

([This document](http://docs.python.org/2/extending/newtypes.html) does not seem to address the issue.)

```
typedef struct {

    PyObject_HEAD

    /* Type-specific fields go here. */

     struct api_query query; /* instead of PyObject * type here */

} api_Request;
```

Comment: What is your objective? What do you  intend to do with the C structure? Pass to some shared library function calls, access it's contents?

Comment: Pass the structs ( request )and get a response (another struct) to a socket, so that the server may give the required result

Comment: The document you link is indeed the right source. Read it carefully; it does answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

Building an extension module is not a trivial task (the document you linked to does explain how to do it in detail). To wrap a C structure that way, you need to define the new type and a Python's object usual methods (constructor, destructor, access methods, etc...).

You might find the [`ctypes`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html) package is an easier way to go about it.

Better still, if all you need to do is create the structure and send it (to a socket, as you say), and if the structure is simple enough, then the [`struct.pack`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/struct.html?highlight=struct#struct.pack) function might prove easiest.